# IntelliSense Error C Programming

Tags: c

I was working on the C assignment and being getting some errors for the following code

```
char BA[20] = "Hellow there";
char *pBA;
*pBA = &BA;
```

There is a red line under * and & in the third line of the code. I am getting these errors:

1. IntelliSense: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
2. IntelliSense: a value of type "char (*)[20]" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int *"

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: What do you want the third line to do?  You're trying to assign the *address* of an array to an *uninitialised dereferenced* pointer.

Comment: `pBA = BA;` should suffice.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually, the error is at line 3.

```
char BA[20] = "Hellow there";
char *pBA;
pBA = BA;   //Note :- Address must be passed to a pointer, not to value at the pointer, *pBA means value at pBA
```

This will solve your purpose! I hope you found your mistake.

Comment: `&BA` is not `char *`, its `char (*)[20]`. This is C, so it will likely "work", but should at least generate a warning due to the different types.

Comment: I did that using CodeBlocks, it's not showing any error!!! Rather, I printed both &BA as well as pBA values using printf(). It reflects the answer correctly!

Comment: Yes, that's not running with high compiler warnings.

Comment: Attempting to store a `char (*)[20]` value into the `char[20]` pointed to by `NULL`? [Not sure if you're serious or trolling...](http://memecrunch.com/meme/1UEIH/not-sure-if-you-re-serious/image.png)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour- That was a year ago and I understood my mistake that very day. Can't do much except for receiving the downvotes as I even can't delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is -

```
char BA[20] = "Hellow there";
char (*pBA)[20] = &BA;
```

OR

```
char BA[20] = "Hellow there";
char (*pBA)[20] = NULL;
*pBA = &BA;
```

That said, pointers to arrays are quite rare in C, instead use pointers to pointers.

Comment: Attempting to store a `char (*)[20]` value into the `char[20]` pointed to by `NULL`? [Not sure if you're serious or trolling...](http://memecrunch.com/meme/1UEIH/not-sure-if-you-re-serious/image.png)